# How to use apache 403 error as routing technique with htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a simple php web application with this directory structure

```
.
├── custom_403.html
├── custom_404.html
├── home
│   └── home.php
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
├── login
│   └── login.php
├── public
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── css
│   ├── error_pages
│   ├── fontawesome
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── js
├── signup
│   └── signup.php
├── test.php
```

I made an `.htacess` file that basically looks like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /public/error_pages/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /public/error_pages/500.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

When I type something like `http://localhost/login/` it should give me a `403 Forbidden` error because the directory `login` exists but doesn't have the file `index.php`. According to my `.htacess` it should serve the default `index.php` file.I take advantage of this on the `index.php` to load the file in the specified path from the adress bar using jquery.
I search for `window.location.pathname` to load the corresponding file from that path with a `resolveUrl()` function.

Here's an example

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Boostrap 4.3 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <!-- Fontawesome 5 Free -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/fontawesome/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
  <script src="/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg r-shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img width="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/marvel-comics-logo-31D9B4C7FB-seeklogo.com.png" alt="" srcset=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="signup">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container mt-3 rounded" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); ">dcfdcf</div>
    <div id="loader">
      <div class="spinner"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  function resolveUrl(url) {
    if (url) {
      var path = url.replace(/\//gi, '').trim();
      $(".container").load("/" + path + "/" + path + ".php");
      return path;
    } else {
      $(".container").load("/home/home.php");
      console.log(path)
    }
  }

  function resolveActiveTab(pathName) {
    $(".nav-item").removeClass("active");
    if (pathName) {
      $("li > a[href='" + pathName + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    } else {
      $("li > a").first().parent().addClass("active");
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(window.location.pathname)
    var currentPath = resolveUrl(window.location.pathname);
    resolveActiveTab(currentPath)

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
      $("#loader").css({
        "display": "block"
      });
    })
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
      $("#loader").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    })

    $('.nav-link').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var path = $(this).attr("href");

      $(".container").load("/" + path + "/" + path + ".php");
      resolveActiveTab(path)
      window.history.pushState("", "", "/" + path);
    })
  })
</script>

</html>
```

this means that if the refresh the page with a path like `http://localhost/login/` the jquery will load `login.php`.

This works fine except I get an error on the apache log that looks like this

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/test/login/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

When I try to solve this problem by changing the filenames from `login.php signup.php etc` to `index.php` I get served those files back since they do exist, meaning I won't get the `403` error. I tried denying access to these specific files in my `.htaccess` but then they are denied for everything including the jquery `.load()` function. My question is how do what I'm doing efficiently without the apache error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` is wrong, you are using `ErrorDocument` `403` to load a file `index.php`, (`ErrorDocument` is used normally for custom error pages not for loading a normal resource) you wish have a `Forbidden` when try to load `login/` because this folder doesn't have a `index.php` file but I suspect that you have in your `VirtualHost` the option `Indexes`, this directive loads the folder contents but doesn't serve a `403` error.

My `VirtualHost` for testing purpose is:

```
<VirtualHost localhost-test:80>
  ServerName localhost-test
  ServerAlias localhost-test
  ErrorLog "logs/localhost-test-error.log"
  TransferLog "logs/localhost-test-access.log"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Web/test"
    <Directory />
      Require all granted
      Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you remove `Indexes` from your `VirtualHost` you can see the `Forbidden` error custom page. You should have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /public/error_pages/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /public/error_pages/500.php
ErrorDocument 403 /public/error_pages/403.php
```

Now if you try to load the folder `/login/` without an `index.php` file inside, you should have a `Forbidden` `403` with your custom page error but using JQuery in meanwhile you can load the `login.php` file instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have familiarity with everything you have said but my problem is I want to use folder names as paths/routes in my application. So when someone loads `http://localhost/login` it doesn't try to access the login folder but but my jquery loads the content from `login/login.php`

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346486/how-to-show-directory-index-in-apache-2-4-with-custom-document-root

Comment: Using option `Indexes`  in your `VirtualHost` or `.htaccess` you can fix the error in the log but you cannot get `Forbidden 403` when you are accessing the folder structure...

Comment: Did you try to put inside the folder login a index.php with header("location: login.php"); ?

Comment: Did you try to put inside the folder `login` a file `index.php` and call it like `index.php?option=login` and `index.php?option=signup` and `index.php?option=home` ? Then using `switch` you perform some actions eg `case 'login': header("Location: login.php"); break; case 'signup': header("Location: signup.php"); break; case 'home': header("Location: ../index.php"); break;` etcetera. Mine is only and idea.

Comment: Yes, the problem of someone easily accessing the files inside the, say `login` by easily typing them out on the adress bar.

Comment: What do you think about doing a `referer` check instead? For example, if the `login.php` file has `www/login/index.php` as referer it is ok, while if the `referer` is empty it means that the user has direct access to the `login.php` file and in this case after a check put a beautiful `exit();`

`if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  exit("Direct Access to this File not Allowed");
}`

Comment: Thank you I managed to find a solution which turned out to be there the entire time, I'm just not familiar with apache. It's the ReWrite engine in `.htaccess`. `RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^(login|signup|home)/?$    index.php    [NC,L] ` this helped a lot. But you are right on checking with php what type of request I'm looking at. My work around was `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
            if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']== "XMLHttpRequest"){`

Comment: Use `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'` instead... `XMLHttpRequest` name can be different... Glad to help.